# accessing second value in python list loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to access the second value in list created from a json object. When accessing the first value`"name"` I have no problems. But when trying to access `"address"` i get a error

```
Result: Failure
Exception: KeyError: 'address'
```

The json coming in looks like this

```
{
  "DataToCompare": [
    {
        "name": "Alex Young",
        "address": "123 Main Street"
    }
  ],
  "DataSetAgainst": [
    {
        "name": "Bob Doll",
        "address": "555 South Street"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bob Young",
        "adress": "123 Main St."
    }
  ]
}
```

In the example below `dataBack["address"] = i["address"]` is where the error comes in. If I comment it out I get results back for `name` and `name match`

```
def processing_request(dataIncoming):

    data_to_compare = dataIncoming["DataToCompare"][0]

    dataList = []
    for i in dataIncoming["DataSetAgainst"]:
        dataList.append(i)

    dataResults = []

    for i in dataList:
        dataBack = {}

        clean_name = ''.join(e for e in i["name"] if e.isalnum())
        sequence = difflib.SequenceMatcher(isjunk=None, a=data_to_compare["name"], b=clean_name)
        difference = sequence.ratio()*100
        difference = round(difference, 1)

        # works
        dataBack["name"] = i["name"]
        dataBack["name match"] = difference

        # doesnt work
        dataBack["address"] = i["address"]

        dataResults.append(dataBack)

    return json.dumps(dataResults)
```

Comment: Working on it...

Comment: Dude. You made a mistake writting `"address": "123 Main St."`

Comment: You define two different values, "address" and "adress". Look the Json. @Alex Daniels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears to be a result of a typo:

```
{
  "DataToCompare": [
    {
        "name": "Alex Young",
        "address": "123 Main Street"
    }
  ],
  "DataSetAgainst": [
    {
        "name": "Bob Doll",
        "address": "555 South Street"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bob Young",
        "address": "123 Main St."
    }
  ]
}
```

What did I fix: `"adress": "123 Main St."` to `"address": "123 Main St."`

Output for the code you shared in this case:

`'[{"name": "Bob Doll", "name match": 11.8, "address": "555 South Street"}, {"name": "Bob Young", "name match": 55.6, "address": "123 Main St."}]'`

Answer (score 0):

From the things I see, the error is caused because of a mistake in a:

```
"address": "123 Main St."
```

line. But let's give a benefit of a doubt and assume that data is corrupted and we want to get a workaround for it.

We could transform our `i` value into a list of values in the following way:

```
tab = []
for key in i:
    value = i[key]
    tab.append(value)
```

If we now give order to print tabs, we get in the output:

```
['Bob Doll', '555 South Street']
['Bob Young', '123 Main St.']
```

So, instead of solution above, you could write last line as:

```py
dataBack["name"], dataBack["address"] = tab
dataBack["name match"] = "cookies"
```

As a full answer following your script:

```py
def processing_request(dataIncoming):

    data_to_compare = dataIncoming["DataToCompare"][0]

    dataList = []
    for i in dataIncoming["DataSetAgainst"]:
        dataList.append(i)

    dataResults = []

    for i in dataList:
        dataBack = {}

        clean_name = ''.join(e for e in i["name"] if e.isalnum())
        sequence = difflib.SequenceMatcher(isjunk=None, a=data_to_compare["name"], b=clean_name)
        difference = sequence.ratio()*100
        difference = round(difference, 1)

        tab = [i[key] for key in i]

        # works
        dataBack["name"], dataBack["address"] = tab
        dataBack["name match"] = difference

        dataResults.append(dataBack)

    return json.dumps(dataResults)
```